# how can i disable array of dates in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, datepicker

I want to disable date_dis array from datepicker. I have tried following code.but when i press on txtdate it is showing whole the dates without disable.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var date_dis = ["02-04-2016","03-04-2016","04-04-2016","05-04-2016","06-04-2016","07-04-2016","08-04-2016","09-04-2016","10-04-2016","11-04-2016","12-04-2016","14-04-2016","15-04-2016","17-04-2016","18-04-2016","19-04-2016","20-04-2016","21-04-2016","22-04-2016","23-04-2016","24-04-2016","25-04-2016","26-04-2016","27-04-2016","28-04-2016","29-04-2016","30-04-2016"];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtdate').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-Y', date);
                return [ date_dis.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
            }
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why dont you use min-date and max-date for disable date?

Comment: what datepiker are you using?

Comment: take following script for datepicker.<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

Comment: Working fine mate: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/t4VM5/125/

Answer (score 0):

Use this `dd-mm-yy`

```
<script language="javascript">
    var date_dis = ["02-04-2016","03-04-2016","04-04-2016","05-04-2016","06-04-2016","07-04-2016","08-04-2016","09-04-2016","10-04-2016","11-04-2016","12-04-2016","14-04-2016","15-04-2016","17-04-2016","18-04-2016","19-04-2016","20-04-2016","21-04-2016","22-04-2016","23-04-2016","24-04-2016","25-04-2016","26-04-2016","27-04-2016","28-04-2016","29-04-2016","30-04-2016"];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtdate').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
                return [ date_dis.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
            }
        });  
    });
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm9g61ze/1/)

Comment: Are you sure about `yy` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre It will is not be a problem.

Comment: @RayonDabre `yy` means it will give use the 4 digit format. `y` will give 2 digit format of year.

Comment: I check the demo and its working.but when i click on next and previous month they all are enable. i also want them to disable.how can i do this?

Comment: @zarana you want to disable going to next and previous months?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107920/discussion-between-zarana-and-rejith-r-krishnan).